# jQuery xmlns="..." attribute causing formatting problems in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to dynamically build a table of items.  Below is a simplified version of the code that reproduces the issue I am running into.  Iterating a simple JSON object, I attempt to add a row for each item within the `item` div using jQuery's `append()` method.

*JSON:*

```
var menuTemplate = [
    {
        "label":"First Item",
    },
    {
        "label":"Second Item",
    }
];
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function createMenu() {
    $.each(menuTemplate, function(index, item){
        var row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
        var label = $('<div class="col-sm">' + item['label'] + '</div>');
        row.append(label);
        $('#menu').append(row);
    });
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<body style="background:#ffffff">
    <div id="menu" class="container"></div>
</body>
```

The resultant output is mostly correct, however it contains some `xmlns` attributes on some elements that cause layout problems in Chrome:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="menu" class="container">
    <div xmlns="" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">First Item</div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">Second Item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Firefox and Edge don't seem to have issues displaying the content, but in Chrome, "First Item" and "Second Item" display on the same row with no space in between, as follows:

> First ItemSecond Item

whereas in Firefox and Edge, they are correctly displayed on their own lines as:

> First Item
>
> Second Item

My question is, **Why is the formatting lost with the addition of the `xmlns` attribute?**, and perhaps more essentially, **How do I prevent the `xmlns` attribute from being added in the first place?**

**EDIT:** 
This is what the generated source looks like from the view of the document inspector after the above JavaScript is run on document load:

[image: HTML source as viewed via document inspector]

Comment: Any clue what's adding them? That's not coming from JQuery, at least not under normal circumstances. You might wanna add notes about other libraries in play.

Comment: This is a static web page with with no additional libraries aside from a reference to jQuery 3.4.1 and a stylesheet reference to Bootstrap 4.4.1 css.

Comment: Check your DOCTYPE tag, is it XSLT? If so, that may be the problem.

Comment: cannot reproduce, Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The `div#menu` element is already created. Your script is adding elements to this, not modifying the attributes. I would advise reviewing your Source with JavaScript disabled in Chrome and confirm that these attributes exist first.

Comment: @NathanHawks: Doc type is: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: @Twisty: Yes, correct.  The resultant HTML posted above is obtained using the document inspector in Chrome (i.e., it does not exist until after the page is rendered).  The `createMenu()` function is called via `$(document).ready(function(){createMenu();});` .

Comment: @Lemonseed yes, this is the case, as I said and the element `<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="menu" class="container">` is not created by the `createMenu()` function. As you mentioned it's static content, that element already exists in the HTML Code as is. You could remove the attribute: `$("#menu").removeAttr("xmlns");`

Comment: The document inspector does not show your real source by default. Use the Source tab to confirm the attributes exist in the actual source.

Comment: @Twisty: apologies, I see what you were saying.  @NathanHawks: Viewing the source will not show the elements generated by jQuery.  In any case the inspector is giving me inconsistent results.  Depending on what level of the document I select to inspect, the `xmlns` attribute is either missing, blank, or contains `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.  I am at a loss.

Comment: Assuming these attributes also appear in the other browsers, perhaps a server-side transform is in play, i.e. a server plugin.

Comment: @NathanHawks: This is a local file, so there is actually no server.  I'm starting to suspect that this is an issue with Chrome versus jQuery.  Can't think of any other factors at play.  I've added a screen shot of the document inspector above for additional context.

Comment: Then I second Twisty's suggestion that you shelve the forensic angle and just do a `.removeAttr()` ... Chrome is known to implement weird policies

EDIT: @Lemonseed maybe try a fresh copy of Chrome, it could be a browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  One way that I was able to fix it was by removing the following from the beginning of the document: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >` and replacing with just `<html>`, as well as renaming the extension from `.aspx` to `.html`.  Any technical explanation to why this was effective?  (Remember, this is a local file on my hard drive with no server)

Comment: @Lemonseed you said *remaining the extension from `.aspx` to `.html`* ASPX is a scripting format for .NET. If you're running it locally, it would require some type of Web Service to handle the ASPX content. Sounds like there is more going on here than you lead with.

Comment: Also, the Element Inspector will not show you the Source; it shows you the DOM Elements, including any manipulation from JS/jQuery. Use `View Source` option to see the original HTML in the browser.

Comment: @Twisty: I was making a static page to be eventually added to an IIS website.  That is why I started with the `.aspx` extension.  Since there was no server running and it was simply a static file, and opened directly in Chrome from a local folder on my desktop, there should be nothing special about the file extension being `aspx` vs `html` (or so I thought).  I can't think of a technical reason why Chrome would handle elements added with jQuery differently based on file extension.

Comment: View source only shows `<div id="menu" class="container"></div>` with no insight into how the elements are dynamically added from JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: @Lemonseed if the Source shows the DIV without the attribute, this suggests something added the attribute to the element after the fact. I don't have Chrome or the original content to test with, so you can investigate further if you want, but it sounds like you addressed it on your own.